Public Disclosure of Group Secret Hash in P2P CAS System
I'm developing a P2P Content Addressable Storage (CAS) system with end-to-end encryption, using group keys for access control. The group key is a cryptographic artifact, containing secrets encrypted for multiple recipients. These keys are generated using libsodium, assuming all its security guarantees and drawbacks.
To manage access, I'm considering adding a hash of the group secret as a public identifier for requesting the key.
Are there known risks with publicly disclosing a hash of a secret key in this context?
Are there existing systems or publications that use a similar approach?
